# Como evitar conflito entre jQuery e Mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

Quais as boas prácticas para evitar conflictos entre as bibliotecas jQuery e Mootools?

Este [**exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p94jX/) dá o erro `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fade'`

```
//codigo Mootools
$('sobreCamada').fade('in');

//codigo jQuery
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#sobreCamada').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).remove()
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Trabalho bastante com Mootools e sei que há pouca documentação sobre esta questão em Português, daí a pergunta-resposta.

Comment: Dado a perguntar ter pouco conteúdo, o sistema sinaliza a mesma para revisão por esse motivo. Sugeria aplicar um ou outro erro comum resultante do referido conflito. Desta forma a pergunta tem algum código e conteúdo. Por outro lado, é interessante para que no futuro quem se depare com este problema sem saber que é uma questão de conflito, através dos erros na pergunta, vai conseguir associar e ver a resposta :)

Comment: @Zuul, tens razão. Adicionei um exemplo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma vez que ambos [**Mootools**](http://mootools.net/), [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) (e até [**Prototype**](http://prototypejs.org/)) usam o dollar `$`, o dollar é o problema que tem de ser resolvido e a fonte de conflito entre as dua bibliotecas.

O mootools usa o `$()` para selecionar elementos pelo ID. Assim o código Mootools `$('meuId')` é o semelhante ao método do jQuery `$('#meuId')`. O Mootools tem uma alternativa para selecionar um elemento pelo ID, usando `document.id('meuId');`

### Opcções diferentes:

---

- Ordem de carregamento dos scripts:

O Mootools detecta se o dollar `$` já está a ser utilizado e não re-declara a função `$()`, assim, se o Mootools fôr o ultimo a carregar o problema deve desaparecer. Neste caso deve usar-se `document.id()` no Mootools em vêz de `$()`;

---

- `jQuery.noConflict()`

O jQuery tem um método para libertar o dollar e entrar em [**modo de não conflito**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Na prática até é possivel usar `var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();` e daí em diante chamar o jQuery por `jQ()` em vez de `$()` ou `jQuery()`. O mais habitual é usar `jQuery()` em vez de `$()`, como é o caso do **Wordpress** que carrega o jQuery em modo de não conflito.

---

- `(function($){/*...*/})(jQuery)`

Outra opção é mudar o scope do dollar. Passando o dollar como parâmetro de uma função anónima, esta soluçõa é prática para empacotar código já existente sem ter de mudar todos os `$` para `jQuery`. Esta variante precisa tambem da declaração `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar conflito entre essas bibliotecas você pode criar um closure e limitar para um certo escopo as variáveis criadas e definidas

Para fazer isso em JavaScript utilizamos de funções

```js
function criarClosure(){
    //Aqui está definido um closure
    //E todas as variáveis estão limitadas ao escopo da função
}
```

Então no caso do jQuery, você pode criar uma função anônima que já é executada

```js
(function($){
    //Utilização padrão do jQuery
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ...
    });
})(jQuery); //Nessa linha executamos a função definida sem conflitos
```

No site do jQuery existem mais informações sobre isso (em inglês)

## [Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)