# Erro de: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <link href="~/Content/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Menu.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-color.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Util.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Pesquisa/Pesquisa.js")"></script>
```

Aqui dá o erro citado acima:

```
$("#txtCnpjPesquisa").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
```

Como resolvo.

Minha função jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //$("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
    //$("#phone").mask("(99) 999-9999");
    //$("#cep").mask("99.999-99");
    //$("#cpf").mask("99.999.999-99");
    $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
});
```

Seguindo a sugestão do Filipe e GuilehermeBernal, ficou assim meu cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Menu.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-color.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Util.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Pesquisa/Pesquisa.js")"></script>
```

Comment: por que o downvote?

Comment: Cara, o que você postou ai em cima não ajuda, isso não é o seu código, é apenas os includes. Verificou se o elemento com o id "txtCnpjPesquisa" existe? Substitui esses includes todos pelo seu código.

Comment: @pnet, dá erro em cima onde? Tenta ser mais especifico

Comment: O erro dá nessa linha da minha função jquery: $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");

Comment: esse código está onde? dentro de qual ficheiro?

Comment: O que mais tenho que fazer. Quando alguém não entende, vota negativo só porque não entendeu a pergunta?

Comment: @pnet, o que é o ficheiro `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>` ? Acho que você está a incluir o jQuery 5 vezes... eu tiraria todos menos a versão 2.1 min. E a partir daí ia corrigindo o problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para passar o `jQuery` como alias do `$` ( e assim [evitar conflitos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/769/como-evitar-conflito-entre-jquery-e-mootools)) deve fazer assim:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // O seu código com dolar aqui      
  });
})(jQuery);
```

À parte deste detalhe parece-me que está a incluir 5 versões do jQuery no mesmo documento. Isso vai (está a) dar problemas. Escolha uma e retire as outras. Se possivel mantenha a ultima...

Assim o seu código poderia ser:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    //$("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
    //$("#phone").mask("(99) 999-9999");
    //$("#cep").mask("99.999-99");
    //$("#cpf").mask("99.999.999-99");
    $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Em relação a versões do jQuery, 4 parece-me ser:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")"></script>
```

e possivelmente a última, mais em baixo:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
```

Só deve ter uma.

Comment: Sugiro deixar a 1.10 por ainda ser compatível com a versão 8 do IE, que ainda tem bastante utilizadores.

Comment: Filipe, tenho feito conforme me tens sugerido, mas continua dando pau. Tirei tudo, inclusive o link do css e mesmo assim continua dado erro na máscara.

Comment: Acho que era o jquery.js. Retirei-o conforme me sugeriu e parece-me que resolveu.

Comment: @pnet ótimo que o problema foi resolvido, não falei sobre o jquery.js porque poderia ser código seu e não a biblioteca jquery, poderia ser apenas coincidência de nomes.

Comment: @Sergio, sua dica foi mio

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
});
```

Outra coisa, você está fazendo includes duplicados, os ficheiros com ".min.js" são versões mais limpas, ou seja, sem espaços e comentários, o load desses ficheiros é mais rápido quando se abre uma página.

Remova as seguintes linhas (includes duplicados):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")"></script>
```

Você também está incluindo duas versões do jquery:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")"></script>
```

Elimine uma versão, sugiro que fique com a versão 1.10 por ser compatível com o IE8, apague as linhas:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Como assim includes duplicados. Realmente entendi a questão das versões, mas o maskedinput se eu retirar não consigo mais mascarar campos

Comment: `jquery-1.10.2.js`, `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`, `jquery-2.1.0.js`, `jquery-2.1.0.min.js`, `jquery.js` são CINCO cópias do jquery sendo incluídas. Use apenas uma. E se você usou o arquivo minificado não precisa usar o não minificado.

Comment: @pnet não retire o maskedinput, foi incluído e não me apercebi, peço desculpas.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal sim, inclui isso na resposta.

Comment: Fiz conforme o pedido e continua dando o mesmo erro. E também não reconhece esse link:<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

Comment: Desculpe-me, mas o que é arquivo minificado

Comment: @pnet Como as duas respostas dizem, O `$` não está definido no argumento da função. Use `jQuery(function() {...});` sem o argumento ou alguma variante disso. Arquivo minificado é igual ao não minificado, mas escrito usando menos bytes para compactar. Os dois tem a mesma funcionalidade.

Comment: @pnet minificados são arquivos compactados, ou seja, livre de comentários, quebras de linha e dependendo do tipo de minificador que é utilizado ele pode até alterar a nomenclatura de suas variáveis para conseguir diminuir ao máximo o tamanho de seu arquivo. Arquivos minificados são carregados mais rapidamente que por consequência melhoram o desempenho do site.

Answer (score 0):

estava com um problema semelhante e resolvi com o seguinte código

```js
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // O seu código com dolar aqui      
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -2):

No meu caso, esse erro acontecia porque eu estava carregando o arquivo.js que chamava o .mask antes do jquery. Depois de corrigir a ordem que os arquivos eram carregados o erro não ocorreu mais.