# Retirar um manipulador de eventos apos 3 click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho este código, que preciso que o evento click seja removido depois de x tentativas.

**Exemplo:** http://jsfiddle.net/welguri/s0x213jL/

```
var qtdadeCliques = 0;
var eventCon = function(evento){
    qtdadeCliques++;
    if (qtdadeCliques >= 3) {
        alert("You clicked the div 'red'!");
       $(this).off(evento);
    }
};
$("#div3").on("click", eventCon);
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? Aqui, esse código está funcionando normal...

Comment: O estranho é que quando coloco na pagina do site da este erro: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. @FelipeAvelar

Comment: tente colocar dentro desse bloco de codigo:   (function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // O seu código com dolar aqui      
  });
})(jQuery);

Comment: Qual a versão do jQuery que o site está usando? Antes de checar isso coloque seu código dentro de $(function(){ /*AQUI*/ })

Comment: Funcionou @GabrielRodrigues.

Comment: a solução foi pega daqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/769/como-evitar-conflito-entre-jquery-e-mootools

Comment: Se a `#div3` já existir na página no momento em que você chama o `on`, precisa também corrigir a chamada ao `off`. Você deve passar `eventCon` em vez de `evento` (como na resposta do paulo abaixo).

Answer (score 3):

Faltam alguns detalhes para isso funcionar:

o método `.off()` está mal configurado:

O método pode ser usado sem parametros mas aí vai remover **todos** os event handlers adicionados com o `.on()`, meio perigoso/imprevisivel. O melhor é defenir qual o tipo de evento (e não o objeto evento em sí como tinhas), e já agora para ser seguro passar a função que se quer anular. Ou seja:

```
$(this).off("click", eventCon);
// ou somente $(this).off(); que desaconselho
```

Outro problema já referido é a questão de o código estar a ser corrido antes de o DOM estar pronto. Isso resolve-se envolvento `$("#div3").on("click", eventCon);` com uma função domready do jQuery. Exemplo:

```
$(function () {
    // código a correr aqui...
});
```

#### Assim o código todo seria:

```
$(function () {
    $("#div3").on("click", eventCon);
});

var qtdadeCliques = 0;
var eventCon = function (evento) {
    qtdadeCliques++;
    if (qtdadeCliques >= 3) {
        alert('Chegou a 3!');
        $(this).off('click', eventCon);
    }
};
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5m779gn5/

Answer (score 1):

Coloque o .on() dentro do Ready do Jquery.

```
 (function($) {
    $(function() { 
      $("#div3").on("click", eventCon); 
    }); 
  })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

O trecho abaixo tem uma abordagem um pouco diferente das demais citadas, é utilizado o design pattern **IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)**. A idéia é evitar poluir o contexto global (window) com variáveis desnecessárias. Recomendo a leitura da [API do jQuery onde é explicada a utilização do método off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) e o [post do Ben Alman sobre IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $(document.documentElement).on("click", (function(){
            var clicksCount = 0;

            return function clickFn(event) {
                if (++clicksCount < 3) return;

                alert("Three!");
                $(this).off("click", clickFn);
            };
        }()));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

O exemplo pode ser verificado no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chalassa/tj2L9ykn/)