# MooTools interfere no jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, mootools

Bom dia.

Meu site utiliza jQuery, porem preciso adicionar um código que manda um `confirm()` para fechar o navegador, porem percebi que apenas funciona com a biblioteca [mootools](/questions/tagged/mootools):

```
window.addEvent('load', function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;

        // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = 'Any string';
        }

        // For Safari
        return 'Any string';
    };
});
```

há algum problema em adicionar essa biblioteca? 
Pode acabar interferindo na da `jquery.min`?

Comment: Podes colocar mais código? mais informação sobre o problema? Para informação: O MooTools e o jQuery [podem coexistir com alguns cuidados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/769/129).

Comment: Não tem problema ainda... só quero saber se as duas bibliotecas estiverem juntas no script da pagina terá alguma interferência em ambas? Se elas entram em conflito. @Sergio

Comment: Podem entrar em conflito, fácil de resolver. Mas se colocares mais código posso ajudar-te a usar apenas uma delas, já que é preferível ter só uma. Senão esta pergunta é no fundo duplicata desta: -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/769/129

Comment: É que preciso de um código que exiba um confirm() ao querer fechar o navegador, mas consegui esse código que trabalha com MooTools.

Comment: Se é só essa a razão podes mudar a primeira linha para `window.addEventListener('load', function () {` e já não precisas do MooTools. Testa.

Comment: uhuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu hehehe vlwww manooo kkk

Answer (score 1):

Esta linha com código MooTools:

```
window.addEvent('load', function(){
```

em JavaScript nativo será

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
```

Essa linha adiciona à `window` um oscultador de evento para quando a página tiver carregado.

Se é só essa linha que precisas do MooTools então podes remover a biblioteca e usar só jQuery. Isto sem desprezo para a biblioteca MooTools com a qual eu próprio estou envolvido, mas neste caso específico é desnecessária.

Em relação a possiveis conflitos entre MooTools e jQuery [já respondí sobre isso aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/769/129)